# "ElementNotVisibleException" and "InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted" while trying to click on an element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to automate the download of information from the company web-portals. I need to specify a custom date range (in other parts of the code).

The page html is in the following format

```
<div id="datePickerIconWrap" class="float_lang_base_2 datePickerIconWrap"><span class="datePickerIcon">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

I have tried specifying the item by either `class_name` and `id`; but both fails

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
url = '<my url>'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("Y:/Users/admin/Documents/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('datePickerIconWrap').click()    
driver.find_element_by_class_name('float_lang_base_2 datePickerIconWrap').click()
```

I get the error message below for .find_element_by_id

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

I get the error message below for .find_element_by_class

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
(Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
```

Answer (score 0):

About the errors:

- This error message `ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible` implies that the desired element was not visible within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- This error message `InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted` implies that the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you have adapted was not a valid one.

### Solution

To invoke `click()` on the desired element you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.float_lang_base_2.datePickerIconWrap>span.datePickerIcon"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='float_lang_base_2 datePickerIconWrap']/span[@class='datePickerIcon']"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```